# How to check the nested element within line_format expression in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, go-templates, grafana-loki

I am using the `line_format` to create a nicer log message and I want to filter out some nested json labels.

I currently have the following code

```
{application="app", environment="Production", level="error"} 
| pattern `<_entry>` 
| json
| line_format "\033[1;37m{{ .Message }}\033[0m\n{{ range $k, $v := (fromJson ._entry)}}{{if ne $k \"Message\" }}{{if ne $k \"MessageTemplate\"}}\033[1;30m{{$k}}: \033[0m\033[2;37m{{$v}}\033[0m {{ end }}{{ end }}{{ end }}"
```

and I get the following log line:

```
    
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
EventId: map[Id:1 Name:UnhandledException] ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId: 800017c6-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath: /Instrumentation/SetGauge/ SourceContext: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diag
```

The `EventId` is an object with two fields: `Id` and `Name`. Lets say i want to filter out the 'Id` part.

In the `{{ range $k, $v := (fromJson ._entry)}}{{if ne $k \"Message\" }}....{{end}}` part of the code, the `$k` is the `EventId` and the `$v` is the object `{Id:1,Name:'UnhandledException'}`.

I want to add an `if` that filters out the `EventId.Id`.

How to do this?

As a second question; How to combine all these `if`s with and OR? I used `or` and `||` but nothing works, what is the `or` in this language. (What is this script language that i can refer too? Not the LogQl, I mean the line_format scripting language)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use the LogQL analyzer to share examples of queries you are running. It even helps you debug the query itself.

[Here I tried to reproduce your example](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/analyzer/?query=%7C%20pattern%20%60%3C_entry%3E%60%20%20%7C%20json%20%7C%20line_format%20%22%7B%7B%20.Message%20%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%20range%20%24k%2C%20%24v%20%3A%3D%20%28fromJson%20._entry%29%7D%7D%7B%7Bif%20ne%20%24k%20%5C%22Message%5C%22%20%7D%7D%7B%7Bif%20ne%20%24k%20%5C%22MessageTemplate%5C%22%7D%7D%7B%7B%24k%7D%7D%3A%20%7B%7B%24v%7D%7D%20%7B%7B%20end%20%7D%7D%7B%7B%20end%20%7D%7D%7B%7B%20end%20%7D%7D%22&line%5B%5D=%7B%22Message%22%3A%20%22An%20unhandled%20exception%20has%20occurred%20while%20executing%20the%20request%22%2C%20%22ParentID%22%3A%20%2200000001%22%2C%20%22EventID%22%3A%20%7B%22Id%22%3A%201%2C%20%22Name%22%3A%20%22UnhandledException%22%7D%7D).

If only the `EventID` in the json doc contains an object, then you can do an `if` to catch the `EventID` key and process it in a custom way to extract the Name out of the inner object.

As you may know already, the `line_format` uses Go's templating engine under the hood so you can use [its syntax](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#pkg-overview) to index a map (in this case `$v`).

```
| pattern `<_entry>`
| json
| line_format "{{ .Message }}\n{{ range $k, $v := (fromJson ._entry)}}{{if ne $k \"Message\" }}{{if ne $k \"MessageTemplate\"}}{{$k}}: {{if eq $k \"EventID\"}} {{index $v \"Name\"}} {{else}} {{$v}} {{end}} {{ end }}{{ end }}{{ end }}"
```

Note the new `{{if eq $k \"EventID\"}} {{index $v \"Name\"}} {{else}} {{$v}} {{end}}` part.

Here's [an example with LogQL Analyzer](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/analyzer/?query=%7C+pattern+%60%3C_entry%3E%60+%7C+json+%7C+line_format+%22%7B%7B+.Message+%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B+range+%24k%2C+%24v+%3A%3D+%28fromJson+._entry%29%7D%7D%7B%7Bif+ne+%24k+%5C%22Message%5C%22+%7D%7D%7B%7Bif+ne+%24k+%5C%22MessageTemplate%5C%22%7D%7D%7B%7B%24k%7D%7D%3A+%7B%7Bif+eq+%24k+%5C%22EventID%5C%22%7D%7D+%7B%7Bindex+%24v+%5C%22Name%5C%22%7D%7D+%7B%7Belse%7D%7D+%7B%7B%24v%7D%7D+%7B%7Bend%7D%7D+%7B%7B+end+%7D%7D%7B%7B+end+%7D%7D%7B%7B+end+%7D%7D%22&line%5B%5D=%7B%22Message%22%3A+%22An+unhandled+exception+has+occurred+while+executing+the+request%22%2C+%22ParentID%22%3A+%2200000001%22%2C+%22EventID%22%3A+%7B%22Id%22%3A+1%2C+%22Name%22%3A+%22UnhandledException%22%7D%7D).